# Convert Array of ShortInt to String, Delphi

Tags: delphi

I'm doing the way I learned, that is:
with a FOR and taking the Index array one by one, but it is leaving too slow, would otherwise convert it to a String? that leaves quicker?

In my case it would be a Dynamic Array of ShortInt.

For example, given this input:

```
[0,20,-15]
```

I would like the following output:

```
0,20,-15
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect that your code is slow because it is performing unnecessary reallocations of the string. However, without seeing your code it's hard to be sure.

Probably the simplest way to code your algorithm is to use `TStringBuilder`. Whether or not that gives sufficient performance, only you can say.

```
sb := TStringBuilder.Create;
try
  for i := 0 to high(buffer) do
  begin
    sb.Append(IntToStr(buffer[i]));
    if i<high(buffer) then
      sb.Append(',');
  end;
  str := sb.ToString;
finally
  sb.Free;
end;
```

Comment: Sorry return this:
`%PDF-1.5
%âãÏÓ
43 0 obj
<</Linearized 1/L 3016435/O 45/E 1562891/N 2/T 3016048/H [ 479 221]>>
endobj
            
54 0 obj
<</DecodeParms<</Columns 5/Predictor 12>>/Filter/FlateDecode/ID[<8BC0AFA464E020A336FE264E96C0FB99><DB35BD3D43DC9E40A3A43FE559A7BFE6>]/Index[43 24]/Info 42 0 R/Length 74/Prev 3016049/Root 44 0 R/Size 67/Type/XRef/W[1 3 1]>>stream
hÞbbd```b``Z"O‚ÙÇÁd˜\$Yo}±¹šA$[Xedäo’¿þ†30ÍÙÊIþg`Üø
 À`

Comment: @JoseEduardo Presumably you can see what all of the code in my answer and RRUZ's does. If that doesn't do what you want, you need to clarify the question. That said, the `%PDF-1.5` string looks like the code is behaving well.

Comment: I have in my Array [0,150,30,12, -15, -30 ...], and needed to be passed in the same way, but as a concatenated string, Example:
`Array [0] = 0;
Array [1] = 150;
Array [2] = 30; ...`

Already in the string would need something like this:
`String = 0,150,30 ...`

All concatenated, but using `for` is getting too slow...

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, you are right I just check the `_LStrFromPCharLen` implementation and now I understand what do you mean, I will delete my comments in a few seconds :)

Comment: Thank you, for your patience and the help, worked like @David Heffernan me suggested.


thank you

Comment: if you want to squeeze every bit of performance out of this function, try taking the `if i<high(buffer) then` out of the loop.  Setting sb.Capacity before the loop would also contribute to improve performance. (`sb.Capacity := (High(Buffer) + 1) * 5;` would guarantee no memory reallocations, but also would use the highest ammount of memory).

Comment: @Ken Agreed. In practice it makes little measurable difference.